# Descargar documento del servidor

Tags: php

Necesito descargar un documento de la base de la base de datos, es un pdf, pero se me descarga en blanco, ¿Alguien me puede decir en qué falla mi codigo?

La sql está correcta....

```
$id = $_GET['id'];


$sql = "SELECT * FROM documents WHERE id='".$id."'";
$conect = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbpruebas","root", "", array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
$resultado = $conect->query($sql);      
  if (isset($resultado)) {
        $fila = $resultado->fetch();
        if ($fila !== false) {

        $ruta = "./files/" . $fila['filepath'];
           header('Content-Type: application/force-download');
           header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $fila['name'] . ".pdf" );
           header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
           header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($ruta) );
           readfile($ruta);

        }
    }
```

Comment: Pero... ¿en la bd tienes un archivo PDF en sí o tienes solamente almacenada la ruta al PDF?

Comment: En la base de datos tengo la ruta --> filepath

Answer (score 0):

Prueba sustituyendo esto:

```
      header('Content-Type: application/force-download');
      header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $fila['name'] . ".pdf" );
      header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
      header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($ruta) );
      readfile($ruta);
```

por esto:

```
    header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=' . $fila['name'] . ".pdf" );
    header("Content-type: application/pdf");
    readfile("$ruta");
```

Comment: sigue apareciendome en blanco

Answer (score 0):

Acabo de probar este código en mi web y me funciona.

**A. DESCARGAR DIRECTAMENTE:**

```
$archivo="https://www.boe.es/buscar/pdf/2013/BOE-A-2013-12886-consolidado.pdf";
header("Content-Length: " . filesize ($archivo) ); 
header("Content-type: application/pdf"); 
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=".basename($archivo));
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
$filepath = readfile($archivo);
```

**B. MOSTRAR EN LÍNEA**

```
$archivo="https://www.boe.es/buscar/pdf/2013/BOE-A-2013-12886-consolidado.pdf";
header("Content-Length: " . filesize ($archivo) ); 
header("Content-type: application/pdf"); 
header("Content-disposition: inline;     
filename=".basename($archivo));
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
$filepath = readfile($archivo);
```

**NOTA:**

Para más claridad en el código, he puesto el nombre del archivo en una variable `$archivo`, te toca a ti capturar en `$archivo`  una ruta completa y válida de tu pdf. En este caso he usado este pdf de ejemplo: `https://www.boe.es/buscar/pdf/2013/BOE-A-2013-12886-consolidado.pdf` Si quieres lo puedes probar en un php cualquiera de tu servidor.

Prefiero las variables, ya que concatenar directamente dentro del código me pone nervioso :) y a veces las cosas te fallan porque en la concatenación directa hay una coma de más o de menos, o un punto de más o de menos.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, este código funciona a la perfección. ¡Muchisimas gracias!

Comment: @AGD_12 Me alegro de que te haya servido. Saludos.